# Pandas aggregate group in a list by condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
| id   | target   | session  | smth             |
| ---- | -------- | -------- | ---------------- |
| 1    | 0        | 1        | np.array(1,2,3)  |
| 1    | 1        | 1        | np.array(5,7,1)  |
| 1    | 0        | 1        | np.array(2,3,4)  |
| 1    | 1        | 1        | np.array(3,4,5)  |
| 1    | 0        | 2        | np.array(2,2,8)  |
| 1    | 0        | 2        | np.array(4,2,0)  |
| 1    | 0        | 2        | np.array(0,0,0)  |
| 1    | 0        | 2        | np.array(1,3,3)  |
| 1    | 1        | 3        | np.array(1,4,4)  |
| 1    | 1        | 3        | np.array(1,5,5)  |
| 1    | 0        | 3        | np.array(1,6,6)  |
| 1    | 0        | 3        | np.array(1,7,7)  |
| 1    | 0        | 3        | np.array(1,8,3)  |
| 2    | 1        | 1        | np.array(1,9,3)  |
```

I need to aggregate all np.arrays in the column "smth", by groups if there are at least two "1" and two "0" values in column target for an each user by their sessions. For example, for this DataFrame we will get:

UPD: I need to save target, otherwise it's impossible to restore them.

For id "1":

```
[[0, np.array(1,2,3)], [1, np.array(5,7,1)], [0, np.array(2,3,4)], [1, np.array(3,4,5)]]
[[1, np.array(1,4,4)] , [1, np.array(1,5,5)], [0 ,np.array(1,6,6)], [0, np.array(1,7,7)], [0, np.array(1,8,3)]]
```

That is an extremely hard aggregation

Tried many group by methods, but this is really hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
(df.groupby(['id', 'session'])
   .apply(lambda d: list(zip(d['target'], d['smth']))
          if d['target'].value_counts().reindex([0, 1]).ge(2).all()
          else None
         )
   .dropna()
)
```

Output:

```
id  session
1   1          [(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [5, 7, 1]), (0, [2, 3, 4]...
    3          [(1, [1, 4, 4]), (1, [1, 5, 5]), (0, [1, 6, 6]...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am really sorry, but I just realised that I don't want to lose target for an each array. How can I make it? To have like [[target, array], [target, array], [target, array]]

Comment: what would be the exact expected output?

Comment: For the above example will be: [[0, np.array(1,2,3)], [1, np.array(5,7,1)], [0, np.array(2,3,4)], [1, np.array(3,4,5)]]
[[1, np.array(1,4,4)] , [1, np.array(1,5,5)], [0 ,np.array(1,6,6)], [0, np.array(1,7,7)], [0, np.array(1,8,3)]]